# Mono android not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I my visual studio 2010 i add mono android.And i installed android sdk and java sdk.But it always shows

> 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8'.
>   Ensure you have installed support for this Android platform version in
>   the Android SDK Manager.  C:\Users\Dell\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\aresgen MonoAndroidApplication1

How to slove this?

Answer (score 0):

Start Android SDK Manager either from inside Visual Studio or from the location "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat".

Once its done loading packages... checkmark "Android 2.2 (API8)" to install support and your error will be resolved.

Alternatively, if you are not planning to support Android 2.2 and are fine with the latest Android version, then in Visual Studio, go to Project Properties >> Application and change the API to whatever API you want.

Comment: And? Is your problem still not resolved? If not, then please explain what is not working?